# Sitecore with AD module call WCF Service Windows Identity

Tags: wcf, sitecore, kerberos

We have a Sitecore solution in which all of the users belong to Active Directory.  We have enabled the Active Directory module for Sitecore.  We need need to call a WCF service which uses Kerberos for delegation.  I need to call the service as the logged in user in Sitecore.

Is there any clever way to get a windows identity to use for delegation?

Should I log in the user into windows auth when they log into sitecore and store the token somewhere?